# Facebook PHP SDK: Post object / action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I'm trying to use the PHP SDK to post actions, but it doesn't seem to return an object after the request is made, nor does it update the activity section of the users profile with the action. I had this working fine in JS but can't seem to move it to php.

```
// include the FB SDK
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/facebook/facebook.php');

// create the application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $this->facebookConfig->appid,
    'secret' => $this->facebookConfig->appsecret,
    'cookie' => true
));

// get the user id
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if(!empty($user)) {
    // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
    // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
    try {

        // post og actions
        if(!empty($this->thanksData->ogobject) && !empty($this->thanksData->ogaction)){

            $method = '/me/' . $this->appData->namespace . ':' . $this->thanksData->ogaction;
            $params = array(
                        $this->thanksData->ogobject => 'http://mydomain.com/thanks', 
                        //'access_token' => $this->fbAuthToken
                    );

            $ret_obj = $facebook->api($method, 'POST', $params);

        }

        // wall post
        if(!empty($this->facebookConfig->wallmsg))
            $this->wallPost($facebook);

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $params = array(
            'scope'         => $this->permissions,
            'redirect_uri'  => $this->facebookConfig->applink
        );
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

        // log errors
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());

        // redirect if not logged in or not enough permissions
        //echo "<script>top.location=\"".$loginUrl."\";</script>";die;
    }

    // Give the user a logout link 
    //echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
}
```

**Example of the same in JS**
This code was working before I removed it in favour of doing the task in PHP

```
// initialise facebook
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    // get the data
    var data = $('body').data();

    FB.init({
        appId   : data.appid, // App ID
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
        oauth   : true  // oauth stuff
    });

    // enable actions on page visit
    if(data.object.length > 0 && data.action.length > 0){

        // check if we have permissions
        FB.login(function(loginResponse){

            FB.api('me/permissions','get',function(response){

                // get the data
                var data = $('body').data();

                if(data.ogactions == 1){
                    var params = {};
                    params[data.object] = data.url;

                    // post that we read the article
                    FB.api(
                        '/me/'+ data.appnamespace + ':' + data.action,
                        'post',
                        params,
                        function(response) {
                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                console.log(response);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Action successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                            }
                    });

                }

            });

        }, {scope: 'publish_actions,publish_stream'});

    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting can you paste the error log

Comment: Yes I'm using zend framework, and the error log has no errors, dumping ret_obj doesn't do anything, I have to move the dumps above the api query but cannot dump the actual api request

Comment: Can you share your working JS code , Just to compare , because I suspect it wont work in JS also because ret_obj is not returning anything , are  you using the correct  appid generated , because appid generated is specific to domain . and the domain you are using and domain for which appid generated may be different .

Comment: Domain name using I mean , the url you see when the page bearing this code is viewed in the browser is it matching with the domain name you used to create appid

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara I have updated the code with the JS

Comment: Have you checked that the if condition that publishing depends on in your code is actually true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a rather stupid error, my og meta fields in the head had name="" rather than property="", something I hadn't noticed.